# How can explain this array?

Tags: c#, arraylist

```
 int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(),Int32.Parse);
        int[] f = new int[101];
        
        for(int i=0;i<a.Length;i++)
            **f[a[i]]++;** //can not understand this line.
        
        int c = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<f.Length;i++)
            c += f[i]/2;
        
        Console.WriteLine(c);****
```

What is the explain the line where I comment please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `f[a[i]]++` can be broken down as follows:

- `a[i]` corresponds to the current value found at index `i`. For example in the first run of the loop the value would be `a[0]` and so on. So for example, if you have `a[0]=2`, then then your array will be `f[2]`
- `f[2]` means the value present on the 3rd position of the `f` array
- This value would be incremented by 1

I am not quite sure how are using this value since your `f` array is dependent on the values of `a` array

Comment: I want to find how many pair element in a[ ] using this code